# adding cookies to configuration file in cypress

Tags: cypress

Our environments are defined by cookies for example

```
www.cypress.com with cookie env=dev

QA environment
www.cypress.com with cookie env=qa

PROD environment
www.cypress.com with cookie env=prod
```

1. How to create the config file in Cypress to access these environments.
2. If I want to configuration by cookie + user agent (ex:  www.cypress.com with cookie env=qa and useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1'.
   What is the best way to configure the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to accomplish this in my opinion would be add a json file under your `cypress\fixtures` directory.so for example you added cookies.json in your fixtures directory, here's how you'd then access it:

1st way

```
cy.fixture('cookies.json').as('cookies');
cy.get('@cookies');
```

2nd way

```
cy.fixture('cookies.json').then((cookies) => {
// now you have access to cookies object to manipulate
});
```

here is more info on fixtures from cypress.io docs `https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Usage`
hope this helps